# Using accessibilty service get nodes info of current window in android

Tags: java, android

I have been searching approach that might work i fist need to get the root accessibility node of the current UI using w(). This returns an AccessibilityNodeInfo object representing the root view.

It then traverses the view hierarchy recursively using getChildCount() and getChild() to navigate the subtree.

For each AccessibilityNodeInfo in the hierarchy, it calls getText() to read any text content associated with that node. This text is added to a list.

It also reads the view ID if available using getViewIdResourceName() on the node.

The view text and IDs are stored in maps/lists as the hierarchy is traversed.

I really try coding it several times but i didnt have luck, im expecting if someone can provide me acode explanation of how can approach.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.